# How do i disable Container childs to expand?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

So i got a Container in a Scaffold (Material). But if i add a ElevatedButton as a child of this Container the ElevatedButton the Button Expands to the full size of the parent Container. How can i avoid it?

I don't know whether it's the fault of flutter installation or if it's on me.

Here's the code.

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  String status = "Status: OK";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(status),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SubmitContainer(),
          ],
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InputContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const InputContainer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextField(),
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.yellow,
    );
  }
}

class SubmitContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const SubmitContainer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: SizedBox(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("GO"),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        width: 300,
        height: 50,
      ),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    );
  }
}
```

And the endresult looks like this:
[image: Google Pixel 3a XL API 23]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your `Container` widget's child with a `Center` widget
This way even if the Container itself is wide, the content will have automatic width

```dart
Container(
  child: Center(
    child: //...
  ),
)
```

Check out this page from the documentation for more information
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints#example-3

Comment: @Roaa why should we wrap with `Center` widget only?

Comment: I just added a link to the answer for more information

Comment: @Roaa instead of adding a link explain briefly about it.

Answer (score 7):

When we use `FittedBox` it occupies the content width. Use FittedBox for Button.

```
Container(
        child: SizedBox(
          child: FittedBox(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("GO"),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
          width: 300,
          height: 50,
        ),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      );
```

Comment: It works but is causing a side effect of scaling down the widgets inside it. Is there a way to disable it keeping the feature of preventing the children from expanding more than their size?

Answer (score 1):

You did a mistake. Inside your container widget in **SubmitContainer**, you defined `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,` that is why the elevated button stretched to match the full screen width. Just use do the following:

```
SizedBox(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("GO"),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        width: 150,
        height: 50,
      );
```

Comment: yes but i place it into a container and set the width of container to full width, the elevatedbutton takes the size of the parent

Answer (score 1):

Just one other possible solution is to **wrap your button** inside ***[UnconstrainedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/UnconstrainedBox-class.html)*** widget: "A widget that imposes no constraints on its child, allowing it to render at its 'natural' size."

Comment: OMG that's the perfect solution! This should be the selected answer.